# Internal storage requirements of C++ UnorderedAssociativeContainer

Tags: c++

I've been reading about C++ containers and iterators. For my question, I think the following observations are relevant:

1. [UnorderedAssociativeContainer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/UnorderedAssociativeContainer) is a [Container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container).
2. `value_type` is `std::pair<const Key, T>`.
3. `iterator` is [LegacyForwardIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator) and dereferencing it returns container's `value_type`.

Does this imply that any UnorderedAssociativeContainer must internally store items as `value_type`?

My curiosity stems from a considering the memory footprint of containers. If I have `std::unordered_map<int32_t, int64_t>`, then on 64-bit systems `std::pair<int32_t, int64_t>` will have 32 unused bits due to alignment. I think we should be able to store things more compactly, but I don't see how to satisfy the requirements if the storage is organized in any other way than `value_type`.

How could `iterator` return a reference to `value_type` if the internal storage were organized differently?

Comment: "Does this imply that any UnorderedAssociativeContainer must internally store items as `value_type`?" No, there's no such implication. And neither is it for OrderedAssociativeContainer, which have similar rules.

Comment: The container can store things internally however it wants. As long as it accepts insertions according to the contract and can ensure that when you dereference an iterator you end up with a value of the expected type, then it can store the data as efficiently (or inefficiently) as it wants and do as little or as much calculation and construction on insertion and iterator dereference as it wants/needs to.

Comment: The address of `*iterator->second` must be the address of the value stored in the map, and mutating one must mutate the other. This doesn't leave you with a lot of choice w.r.t. the internal representation.

Comment: Yes, that is the implication. And yes, this rules out certain implementations such as keeping keys and  values in separate arrays for better locality of data during key lookup. The alternative would be to have iterators return proxy objects. But ```vector<bool>``` has shown that this is not usually a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, no. The implementation of the standard library is not constrained by the language standard (in fact, it is impossible to implement the full standard library without relying on compiler extensions). An implementation could rely on some exceedingly unusual processor functionality to tightly pack the elements while still exposing them (including their user-visible memory layout) as `pair`s.

With that said, all standard library implementations I’m aware of do use `pair` for storage.